# How to compile hal mbed on mbed-cli

Tags: c, arm, mbed

I want to compile and run an example on my nucleo board. I am able to compile and flash using the mbed os api. However I have downloaded the STM32Cube_FW_F4_V1.16.0 package and want to run one of those examples. How do I compile this on mbed-cli or do I have to use an ide like MKD_ARM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cant compile them on mbed. Mbed uses HAL libraries anyway behind the scenes on STM32 devices but you cant compile those examples on embed.

The easy way:

Install openSTM32 package

Go to import/general/existing projects into workspace

Find the directory containing your example and SW4STM32 (it contains project files for your IDE)

[image]

Do not tick copy project into the workspace as it breaks include paths.

Finish and you are done.

Compile, run, enjoy

Comment: great thanks and does that mean if I want to compile my own main.c which uses hal libraries I cant on mbed-cli either

Comment: I do not think so. The problem is not the compiler but the configuration of the hundreds of include and source directories and files, them writing the makefile. I reckon many hours of boring, hard and useless work :). It is easier to install ecliple + STM plugins and do something more enjoyable instead

Comment: Is this possible with other targets as well?